# SQL Server, passing stored procedure results by using temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure which uses the result of another stored procedure by using temp table. The inner stored procedure `usp_i` is in database A and the outer stored procedure `usp_o` is in database B. All databases are on the same server.

At the end of `usp_i`, I put its results into the `#tmpResult` table:

```
use A
go

select * into #tmpResult from SomeTable
```

Now in the caller `usp_o`, I have

```
use B
go

exec A.dbo.usp_i
select * from #tmpResult
select * from tmpdb..#tmpResult
```

Both ways I got an error

> Invalid object name #tmpResult

How can I get the temp table across?

Comment: Are you trying to access the results returned by the inner stored proc in the outer store proc ? or do you wanted to use the temp table created in the inner proc in the outer proc?

Comment: @Murthy ultimately I want to use the results returned by the inner proc. I think the easiest is `insert into ... exec` but sql server has some nesting issue with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre create the temp table in usp_o, and in usp_i, insert rows and you will be able to access in usp_o

```
-- in usp_o
create table #tmpResult ( ... )

exec A.dbo.usp_i



-- in usp_i
insert into #tmpResult (  ... ) select ... from sometable
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the temp table in your outer proc and `INSERT INTO` it in your inner proc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use table ##:

```
select * into ##tmpResult from SomeTable
```